# Does Xcode save your answer to the system when agreeing to the License Agreement?

Tags: xcode, license

Upon installing Xcode, it prompts a license agreement. When you press agree, you are never prompted the license agreement again. Does your answer get saved to the system, that way the application does not ask you again? If so, where does the system save the file to?

Comment: To whomever down-voted this question, why? Its a legitimate question. ... To the close voters, what don't you understand about the question? It seems fairly straight forward to me anyway that I believe the answer I posted is on target. StrangeRanger, I upvoted the question to counter the down-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you agree to the **Xcode** license, an entry is created in:

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
```

As shown in the image below:

[image]

Or from **Terminal** using the `defaults` *command*:

```
$ defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist 
{
    IDELastGMLicenseAgreedTo = EA1478;
    IDEXcodeVersionForAgreedToGMLicense = "9.4.1";
}
$
```